# Use tikz commands in caption

Tags: tikz-pgf, subcaption

On a map I used different symbols to indicate different structures. I used [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz) to draw on the screenshot of a map website. I defined three types of symbols:

```
\tikzstyle{ARA} = [blue,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=3, draw, shape border rotate=180,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=10pt,fill=blue]
\tikzstyle{wfluss} = [->,blue,thick]
\tikzstyle{probe} = [red,diamond,draw,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=10pt,fill=red]
```

I want to have the legend (i.e. the part explaining the symbols) to be in the caption, i.e. that the red and blue symbols are explained in the caption.  [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you put these tikz pictures in `\savebox`es, they are safe to use in captions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\tikzset{ARA/.style={blue,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=3, draw, shape border rotate=180,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=10pt,fill=blue},
probe/.style={red,diamond,draw,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=10pt,fill=red}}
\newsavebox{\nodeARA}
\newsavebox{\nodeprobe}
\sbox\nodeARA{\tikz{\node[ARA]{};}}
\sbox\nodeprobe{\tikz{\node[probe]{};}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{\usebox{\nodeARA} represents \dots while \usebox{\nodeprobe} stands for \dots.
}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: BTW `\tikzstyle` is deprecated.

Comment: Thank you! I will update the code and include this new code.

Comment: It also works with \listoffigures, although you lose the spaces after the saveboxes.  \usebox gets expanded as bunch of commands ending with \relax.  You can fix it using `{\usebox\nodeARA}` for example.